# Clipping a multipolygon shapefile with another multipolygon shapefile with Python

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr2ogr

I have two multipolygon shapefiles. The smaller shapefile is contains polygons that represent water areas during a flood. The larger shapefile is of permanent water bodies for a larger area. I would like to clip the smaller shapefile using the larger shapefile to remove the permanent water so that the output is a shapefile of flooded areas in the small region. I have to do this for a number of similar small shapefiles throughout the area spanned by the larger shapefile.

I am working in Python and have tried the following using ogr2ogr:

```
import subprocess

args = ['ogr2ogr', '-clipsrc', large_permanent_water_shapefile, output_shp, smaller_shp]
subprocess.call(args)
```

But when I open the result in QGIS it looks like the largest body of permanent water is removed while the smaller lakes still remain.

I am not a GIS expert by any means so a lot of this stuff I am learning as I go. I have not found many similar examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Geopandas with [overlay difference](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html)

```
import geopandas as gpd

#Create geodataframes
water = gpd.read_file(filename = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/water.shp")
flood = gpd.read_file(filename = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/flood.shp")

#Difference flood with water
flooded_areas = gpd.overlay(df1=flood, df2=water, how="difference")

#Save the result
flooded_areas.to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/flooded_areas.shp")
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly and is so simple I'm surprised I couldn't find it. Thank you.

Comment: Nice! Yes GeoPandas is great, you get both the [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) functionality combined

Answer (score 1):

You can use the arcpy.Erase to do that.

There's the code in Python

```
import arcpy
input_features = fr'C:\flooded_area.shp'
erase = fr'C:\Permanent_Water.shp'
output = fr'C:\MyOutput.shp

arcpy.analysis.Erase(in_features=input_features, erase_features=erase, out_feature_class=output)
```

That's it.
Don't forget to pip install arcpy.
There's the documentation: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/erase.htm

If you want to do that in a loop for lots of shapefiles, you can do it like that:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = fr'C:\Shapefiles_Folder'


input_features = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
erase = fr'C:\Permanent_Water.shp'
output_folder = fr'C:\MyOutputFolder
for fc in input_features:
output_name = fr'{output_folder}\{fc}_erased'
    arcpy.analysis.Erase(in_features=fc, erase_features=erase, out_feature_class=output_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I really should have mentioned that I'm not using arcpy in my original question.